# Why does ~True return the value -2 in Python?

Tags: python

Intuitively, I would think ~True would return False, since ~ is the bitwise "not" operator, but this obviously isn't the case. What is really going on here, and how do I get -2 as a return value?

```
In [0]: ~True                                                                                      
Out[0]: -2

In [1]: ~False                                                                                     
Out[1]: -1
```

Comment: so `True == 1`.

Comment: Bitwise means as in binary. As in numbers.

Comment: `~` is negating *all* of the bits, not just the lowest one.

Comment: `~1 == 2` "~ x : Returns the complement of x - the number you get by switching each 1 for a 0 and each 0 for a 1. This is the same as -x - 1. "

Comment: See [Two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement)

Comment: If you want to reverse the boolean value, you would use the `not` operator

Comment: `~` is a bitwise not operator. You can see what's happening with `bin(True) => '0b1'` (binary notation of `True`), and `bin(~True) => -0b10` (shows that `~True` is the two's complement of `True`).

Comment: This is an unexpected side effect of the `bool` type being a subclass of `int`.  You would naturally expect bools to be represented by a single bit, but they are treated as if they have an infinite number of bits the same as any other integer.